# How to determine whether media files are raw or is it being compressed using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, media

I have some set of media files like jpeg, mp4, avi, png etc. I want to know whether file is raw or is it being compressed by some transcoder. How is that possible using ffmpeg?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "raw"?

Comment: Raw formats which are produced by cameras without any compression being done on that.

Comment: None of the file types you've mentioned are used for that. Raw camera shots typically show up, sensibly enough, as `.raw` files.

Comment: @shilpi_agrawal Just inspect the output from `ffmpeg -i somefile`.

Comment: Thanks. But I did that but I am not able to find any relevant data. Every metadata of downloaded files and camera generated files are same.

Comment: You'll probably need to know the format on which the camera saves its raw files. Then you should specify it by giving `ffmpeg` information on frame size and pixel format (`-pix_fmt` and `-video_size` parameters). To list the pixel formats supported by ffmpeg simply use `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`.